# how play program dvb-t in android?

Tags: android, television

I work for company that product iptv, hbbtv and digital tv software both of server side and client side, so I am in android hybrid set-top box development team, how can I implement an app that do scan, play channel, channel up, channel down and show subtitle ... in this case media receive form coax antenna cable... the tuner of set-top box is amlogic...
there is an app installed in set-top box, but i need develop my own app for do some custom work and task...
please help me...how can i do that?
help with document, library, and open source example project about that...
thank you

Comment: set-top box example:1080P Quad Core Amlogic S805 Android DVB-T2 TV BOX Smart Hybrid Set-top Box

Comment: S805+T2 Quad-core Android4.4 STB Hybrid TV OTT BOX/Set-Top Box

Answer (score 1):

After android 5.0, they have implemented TV apis also inluding lower level tv_input related HAL sources. Compile your tuner firmware with android standalone toolchain and port it to HAL. Take a look at https://source.android.com/devices/tv/

Comment: I read about TIF (TV Input Framework), but that implement on android 5.0 and higher...but my set-top box android version is 4.4, and I can not use that. and my set-top box company do not release update for that...

Comment: If your current tv app is working, you can use current native libraries to do tune and have video by writing a new app and calling them via JNI calls. If it is also not running, you will need to natively compile them (tuner firmware, dvb middleware etc.) via NDK and then call from your app. You need to get the related source code to do all, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be done, but there is much work ahead of you, if you choose to do this yourself:

1) Make some native code that can control the DVB-T2 tuner and read the incoming transport stream.

2) Use the demux of the SoC or write a software TS demuxer (I recommend native code for speed)

3) Start building your DVB software stack, including databases for channel lists, EPG and the like. Maybe you need to record TV events to HDD or SD Card and play them back again? It pays off to use OMX decoders for hardware assisted A/V playback - particularly H.264 and H.265 can make any CPU choke. Look out for mux and codec formats not supported by Android (MPEG2 video is only sometimes supported, LATM/LOAS AAC audio is not, etc.)

4) Write a sweet looking UI on top of the DVB stack's features.

We've done all of this (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.futarque.amoeba) and I can tell you it is a lot of work, even if we already had many years of experience in this field.

We separated the tuner control app (platform specific) from the DVB stack/UI app (platform independent - runs on any Android API 16+ device) and pass the transport stream via IP or a Unix pipe.

Let me know if you are interested in shortcutting and licensing the app or its source code.

Comment: If you wound like to try using Aurora TV with your tuner, you can either expose it as a Sat>IP tuner (RTP/RTSP) or our proprietary tuner API (see http://www.homekitforandroid.com/systemsetup/ under "Using the Tuner").

Comment: hello jensk I am interested in the source code let me know how I can contact whit you and talk about this, my email is tony.barajas86@gmail.com